# Disable Place order button on checkout page until checkout agreement checkbox is checked

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

I need to disable place order button until checkout agreement checkbox is checked. I have written some jquery code to achieve this:

```
$('.action.primary.checkout').attr("disabled",true);

$(".checkout-agreement input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
$('.action.primary.checkout').attr('disabled',false);
});
```

If I run this code through browser the result is shown. However if I put this code in my theme's custom js file, the result is not reflected.

The file is loaded on the checkout page(payment page).

Comment: After adding that to custom js files you need to remove the folder pub/static/frontend and also remove var/cache,var/view_preprocessed and the run the static content deploy command.

Comment: The problem is HTML loads after the js is loaded.

Comment: Try adding setTimeout then.